# Select subsets of collection type values

Tags: sql, collections, cassandra, cql, cql3

Using [CQL3 collection types](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections), how can I select parts of a collection? There are examples given to update and set collection types, but it doesn't seem possible to only query subsets of the values in such a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select a specific element within a collection (yet).

> **[Docs](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections)**
>   You can only retrieve a collection in its entirety. And while we may (or may not) relax that rule a bit in the future, this still means that collections are not meant to be excessively large. They are not a replacement for a proper modelisation into tables.